# bash script does not run when starting a new terminal (windows 10)

Tags: git-bash

I recently got a fresh install of windows 10. I tried to bring over my old bash scripts, with no success. My script does not run, and I get no error messages.

My bashrc has the line: `#!/bin/uc` which is supposed to start the script. I also have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of my script (user/bin/uc.sh).

I tried locating the bash interpreter, and sure enough 'which bash' returns '/usr/bin/bash' instead of the usual '/bin/bash'. I updated the first line of the script, but nothing has changed.

This is a little sample code from my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#start notepad++ with args
function noteplus()
{
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" "$*"
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, don't just mention it.

Comment: Do manual executions of the commands in your bash script still work as expected?

Comment: Federico klez Culloca I do not understand what other code should I post? I already wrote down everything that is relevant. In any case, I added the contents of my script.

Comment: Rann Lifshitz, no, nothing gets executed from the script.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" "$*"` see? Here's your problem. You have to escape those backslashes.

Comment: And for the shebang, I suggest you use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to eliminate any doubt about paths.

Comment: Finally `#!/bin/uc` doesn't start the script. If it's the first line of a script, it defines the interpreter to use for that script. If it's not the first line it does nothing as it is interpreted as a comment

Comment: So, since you didn't share enough info, pick which one of those three may be your issue, as otherwise we're just guessing. If it's not any of those, we can guess harder, or you can share enough information for us to help you solve your issue.

Comment: Federico, I already stated that these scripts came from another system, which means they work. The backslashes in the quotes do not have to be escaped - just to be sure I copied that line into my console, and it started np++.

Comment: Changing the shebang at the beginning of the script to what you recommended (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`) did not work. The `#!/bin/uc` line, as stated, is what I wrote into my bashrc, and it is supposed to start my script when I open a console. Again, this used to work on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `#!/bin/(script file name)` with `source ~/bin/(script file name)` in bashrc, and that did the trick.

Comment: Awesome, for my use case I did this to make it work `bash -c "source script.sh"`